# Physical distance between two places

Tags: java, php, string, distance

I need to measure the physical distance between two places whose names are provided as strings. Since sometimes the names are written slightly differently, I was looking for a library that could help me measure the difference and then combine it with a measure of the latitude and longitude to select the correct matches. Preferred languages: Java or PHP.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Heh, I was confused and edited the title to emphasise rather the wrong focus - the question is probably ultimately still a string distance one, as the accepted answer suggests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). This is a way of measuring how different two strings are from one another.

Hopefully I understood your question correctly; using "distance" in the same sentence as "latitude and longitude" could be confusing!

Comment: My fault.. using "distance" IS confusing. As far as lat and long are concerned I really meant the phisical distance. As far as the strings are concerned I meant the "differences" between the two strings.

The Levenshtein distance seems intresting, it would be perfect if there was a "ready to use" library for distance measuring...

Comment: PHP has a Levenshtein distance function built in: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Answer (score 4):

Although written in c (with python and tcl bindings), [libdistance](http://www.monkey.org/~jose/software/libdistance/) would be a tool for applying several distances metrics on strings/data.

Metrics included:

- bloom
- damerau
- euclid
- hamming
- jaccard
- levenshtein
- manhattan
- minkowski
- needleman_wunsch

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty to translate a piece of C# code I've written to calculate the Levenshtein distance into Java code. It uses only two single-dimension arrays that alternate instead of a big jagged array:

```
public static int getDifference(String a, String b)
{
    // Minimize the amount of storage needed:
    if (a.length() > b.length())
    {
        // Swap:
        String x = a;
        a = b;
        b = x;
    }

    // Store only two rows of the matrix, instead of a big one
    int[] mat1 = new int[a.length() + 1];
    int[] mat2 = new int[a.length() + 1];

    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 1; i <= a.length(); i++)
        mat1[i] = i;

    mat2[0] = 1;

    for (j = 1; j <= b.length(); j++)
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= a.length(); i++)
        {
            int c = (a.charAt(i - 1) == b.charAt(j - 1) ? 0 : 1);

            mat2[i] =
                Math.min(mat1[i - 1] + c,
                Math.min(mat1[i] + 1, mat2[i - 1] + 1));
        }

        // Swap:
        int[] x = mat1;
        mat1 = mat2;
        mat2 = x;

        mat2[0] = mat1[0] + 1;
    }

    // It's row #1 because we swap rows at the end of each outer loop,
    // as we are to return the last number on the lowest row
    return mat1[a.length()];
}
```

It is not rigorously tested, but it seems to be working okay. It was based on a Python implementation I made for a university exercise. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You might get some decent results using a [phonetic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_algorithm) to find slightly misspelld names.

Also, if you use a more mechanical edit distance, you'll probably see better results using a weighted function that accounts for keyboard geometry (i.e. physically close keys are "cheaper" to replace than far off ones). That's a patented method btw, so be careful not to write something that becomes too popular ;)

Comment: How can such a simple (but brilliant) idea be patented? :P Or was it the exact technique to honor the keyboard mapping?

Comment: Because software algorithms can be patented in some legally backwards jurisdictions :) I'm just an engineer so I've never bothered to look up the details there, just trusting the company legal advisors.

Comment: The idea of the phonetic algorithm is very nice. Is there any library to implement this feature?

Comment: The SimMetrics library you found appears to have some phonetics for .NET on http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=123463

Answer (score 0):

I found [SumMetrics](http://www.dcs.shef.ac.uk/~sam/simmetrics.html) in Java, but haven't used it.

Comment: I checked out their Levenshtein implementation, and I dare say that the one I provided in my post uses less memory (although that is less of an issue with short strings).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend either [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or the [Jaccard Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_distance) for comparing text.