# Distance between two strings

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, distance

I don’t believe the standard library provides anything to compute the distance between two strings and I can’t seem to find anything in Boost StringAlgo. So, is there any other library I could use?

I am not too picky about the algorithm. Jaro-Winkler is fine, Levenshtein too, and I am open to suggestions, I don’t want to code something that someone has already coded..

Comment: What do you mean by "distance between two strings"?

Comment: What about the Hamming distance? This one is easy to code.

Comment: OK, so not just how far apart they are in memory, then. :)

Comment: Jaro-Winkler, Levenshtein, anything that offers me a scale from "very close" to "extremely different".

Comment: I agree that this question is lacking in specifics

Comment: This one looks good: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#C.2B.2B (#3 hit on Google for "c++ levenshtein distance")

Comment: @SebbyJohanns true. I would not know how to define them though. Ideally I would like to test different metrics and see which one fits my problem best.

Comment: copy paste one of these http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance ?

Comment: I will do that. I secretely hoped that some dusty corner of Boost had that. I don’t like using codes from random sites.

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken, but I really thought any application wanting to do something like “Cannot find 'bla' did you mean 'blu'” would use something like that, so I am surprised it's not standard yet.

Comment: Also #1 Google hit looks good to me: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#C.2B.2B

Answer (score 8):

You don't define your question with an actual distance metric, so I presume it just has to satisfy the conditions in "[Metric (mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Definition)":

> A metric on a set X is a function (called the distance function or simply distance)
>   d : X × X → R
>   (where R is the set of real numbers). For all x, y, z in X, this function is required to satisfy the following conditions:
>
> - d(x, y) ≥ 0     (non-negativity, or separation axiom)
> - d(x, y) = 0   if and only if   x = y     (identity of indiscernibles, or coincidence axiom)
> - d(x, y) = d(y, x)     (symmetry)
> - d(x, z) ≤ d(x, y) + d(y, z)     (subadditivity / triangle inequality).

Suppose we define `d` as such:

```
          { 0 if x = y
d(x, y) = {
          { 1 otherwise
```

So the first three conditions are satisfied:

- `d(x, y) ≥ 0`
- `d(x, y) = 0 iff x = y`
- `d(x, y) = d(y, x) = 0 for x = y`, and `d(x, y) = d(y, x) = 1 for x ≠ y`

For the last condition, there are two cases:

- `d(x, z) = 0`. The only conceivable values for the right-hand side are `0`, `1`, and `2`, any of which would satisfy the condition.
- `d(x, z) = 1`. Suppose that the right-hand side *isn't* greater than or equal to one. This means that it must be zero. Then both terms on the right hand side would each have to be `0`, which means that `x = y` and `y = z`. The second condition means that `x = z`, which in turn means that `d(x, z) = 0`. This is a contradiction, so the right-hand side must be greater than or equal to one.

Then we can define the metric as:

```
int d(std::string x, std::string y) {
    if (x == y) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a mathematician, I like your answer :)

Answer (score 6):

You could try [SimString](http://www.chokkan.org/software/simstring/).

> SimString is a simple library for fast approximate string retrieval.
>   Approximate string retrieval finds strings in a database whose
>   similarity with a query string is no smaller than a threshold. Finding
>   not only identical but similar strings, approximate string retrieval
>   has various applications including spelling correction, flexible
>   dictionary matching, duplicate detection, and record linkage.
>
> SimString supports cosine, Jaccard, dice, and overlap coefficients as
>   similarity measures. SimString uses letter n-grams as features for
>   computing string similarity.

Or the [SimMetric](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/) library.

> SimMetrics is a Similarity Metric Library, e.g. from edit distance's
>   (Levenshtein, Gotoh, Jaro etc) to other metrics, (e.g Soundex,
>   Chapman). Work provided by UK Sheffield University funded by (AKT) an
>   IRC sponsored by EPSRC, grant number GR/N15764/01.

Or the [libdistance](http://www.monkey.org/~jose/software/libdistance/) library, which has implementations of the Levenshtein, Dameru, Needleman-Wunsch, Hamming, Bloom Filter, Jaccard, and Minkowski distances.

[Phonetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_algorithm) may also be of interest.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83777/are-there-any-fuzzy-search-or-string-similarity-functions-libraries-written-for).

Comment: And [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907997/string-distance-library).

Comment: Also checkout https://github.com/Martinsos/edlib for C/C++ implementation of Levenshtein distance!

Answer (score 0):

[This related question contains a code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/908157/154306) demonstrating the Levenshtein distance. It has also been [implemented for MySQL in this C code](https://github.com/jmcejuela/Levenshtein-MySQL-UDF/blob/master/levenshtein.c).